# Nexus has index of jar in Maven Central, but won't download it

Tags: java, maven, gradle, nexus

So I am setting up a Nexus instance and our build requires an apache jar, that is in the maven central repository. There is an index for it, however nexus will not download the jar, causing my gradle build to fail. I have tried expiring the caches and rebuilding the metadata numerous times. I have also tried restarting nexus. I even tried downloading the jar and uploading it to the releases, but to no avail. How can I resolve this issue/ is there a different direction I can go?

EDIT:

I should provide some backstory, I am creating a secondary CI system to test things out (Jenkins, nexus, gradle). The primary CI system works perfectly, and I am sure that the issue is that - for whatever reason- my secondary nexus has an index for a certain jar, but it is not on the local storage. And when my build system reaches out to nexus for this jar, it will not download it. When I turn discovery on for the Central repo, I get- 
Status: Unsuccessful. 
Message: Missing authtoken

Comment: Maybe a cache in the local maven repository where you built your application. Check your m2 directory if a <resource not available> file is located in the specific path.

Comment: Have You also declared repositories section in build.gradle?

Comment: Do you use your nexus as a proxy for maven central ? If yes, do you NEED to do that ? I am asking because, altough interesting, this is not the simplest setting.

Comment: I have declared repositories in the build.gradle. I will add more backstory.